# PHP / ODBC / DB2 - getting segfault on a special character

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I need to read some data from DB2 table (on IBM AS400), and I connect via ODBC.

In php I get `segmentation fault` when I reach a row that contains special character `±`.

This is the problematic cell - `94-A  50G50G-HD (CR) 1.3±.08MM`

Here is my php code

```
$dbname="dbname";
$username="username";
$password="password";
$connection=odbc_connect($dbname, $username, $password);

$query="SELECT AVDES3 FROM PFDATA.ME01ITEM";
$result=odbc_exec($connection, $query);

while (odbc_fetch_row($result)){
    $AVDES3=odbc_result($result,'AVDES3');
}
```

What would be an work around here? Character escape? Decoding / encoding?

Unfortunately the database is readonly, so I cannot make any change.

**UPDATE**:

100% it's `±` that is causing problems.
This query returned the results and didn't get "segmentation fault"

```
SELECT AVDES3 FROM PFDATA.ME01ITEM WHERE AVDES3 NOT LIKE '%±%'
```

But I need to get all data, including rows that contain `±`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an workaround: replace the special character on the fly inside SELECT query:

```
$query="SELECT REPLACE(AVDES3,'±','+/-') as AVDES3 FROM PFDATA.ME01ITEM";
```

If there is a more elegant one, please feel free to share.